# How to specify redirect URL for OAuth Facebook Login

Tags: django, facebook, oauth

Me and my team are developing a Django Web App and facing a problem with the Facebook Login that we use.

It always gives us this error:
[image]

We have found a solution here on stackoverflow and tried it to add the redirect url into the settings in our Facebook Developer App, like this:
[image]
[image]

We unfortunately still got the same error, please help!

**EDIT:**
Here is the redirect URL: http://byzantium-travel.herokuapp.com/auth/complete/facebook/

We got the URL from this automatic generated url as redirect:
https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?client_id=184420402179166&redirect_uri=http://byzantium-travel.herokuapp.com/auth/complete/facebook/&state=7RILNCVZcUISt8eR5kgLP2JQILgSWWv1&return_scopes=true

Comment: Can you provide your redirect url, since from the pictures we can's see it ?

Comment: Edited, added the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did a stupid mistake, I have to admit. We used the wrong API keys, from another Facebook App we were developing.